# Variable is ignored in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a code snippet in a bat file which reads a text file and echos each line like this.

This one works.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (tags.txt) DO (
    @ECHO %%i
)
```

This one does not work. (Echos `tags.txt`)

```
set file="tags.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
    @ECHO %%i
)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling it to read as a string. Move the quote before file and it should work.

```
set "file=tags.txt"
```

or just remove the quotes altogether.

Comment: This works, until the path or filename contains spaces or & characters.  The following will always work `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "c:\folder A\test file.txt" ') do echo(%%a` as will the answer by Magoo.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
FOR /F "usebackqtokens=*" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
```

You need the `usebackq` directive to tell `for` that the quoted string is a filename, not a literal.

Comment: +1 I accepted the other answer for the simplicity, but this one is also good to remember.